# Clicking "Cancel" in the authorization window will throw an error

Tags: javascript, google-oauth, google-picker

I am implementing Google Picker for a web application I am working on, and recently I have been refactoring the code. It is when I noticed that when the user clicks "Cancel" in the auth window, instead calling the callback that is passed to `gapi.auth.authorize`, now clicking "Cancel" will throw an error. This worked just a week ago. It prints this error in console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'error' of null    cb=gapi.loaded_0:430
f.callback                                                  cb=gapi.loaded_0:430
Mw                                                          cb=gapi.loaded_0:421
(anonymous function)                                        cb=gapi.loaded_0:427
(anonymous function)                                        cb=gapi.loaded_0:422
g                                                           cb=gapi.loaded_0:56
c                                                           cb=gapi.loaded_0:47
```

I tried this in the "Hello World" example in Google Picker documentation, I get the same error.

Anyone knows what went wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: I am not surprise because I have seen gapi broken a few times by their updates. The first time I spend hours googling in then end found out the error in google group.

Comment: That was how I found another issue regarding Google APIs that was unrelated to mine, which prompted me to test the "Hello World" example. Same error there.